# ode solver Matlab

Tags: matlab, solver, ode

I am trying to understand the syntax of the ode45 and I don't understand why sometimes it's ode45(odefun, tspan, y0) and other times ode45(@odefun, tspan, y0). I would like to understand the meaning of the @ in front of the function odefun. Especially,the following syntax is not clear to me : (it should solve the equation y'=2*t)

---

```
tspan = [0 5];
y0 = 0;
[t,y] = ode45(@(t,y) 2*t, tspan, y0);
```

---

Does @(t,y) means diff(t,y) ? why are there no sign equal between @(t,y) and 2*t, 
all this remains very mysterious to me ...
If someone could light me, it would be great. 
I thank you very much, 
With best regards,

Comment: Please see the [documentation for anonymous functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

`@odefun` is an older or alternative method to refer to the function `odefun`.

```
@(t,y) 2*t
```

is an anonymous function or lambda expression logically equivalent to

```
function dy = odefun(t,y)
    dy = 2*t
end
```